# jquery disable remaining checkbox when 2 out of 3 unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to limit the ability to uncheck all 3 checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="one" checked>  one
<input type="checkbox" value="two" checked> two
<input type="checkbox" value="three" checked> three


$(":checkbox").click(function() {                             
  if ($("input:checked").length == 2){                                                        
     $(':checkbox(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);  
  }else{                                                        
     $(':checkbox(:checked)').prop('disabled', true); 
  }                                                        
});
```

I can't get it to disable the last checkbox that's left from getting unchecked.
Please help!

http://jsfiddle.net/Vg4ty/81/

Comment: I didnt downvote, but your fiddle is working

Comment: No it disables the other two from being checked again! I should only allow me to uncheck 2 out of 3, but i should always be able to check the uncheck ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  if ($("input:checked").length == 1) {
    $(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(':checked').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="one" checked>one
<input type="checkbox" value="two" checked>two
<input type="checkbox" value="three" checked>three
```

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly it

Answer (score 0):

Capture the click event and then prevent the default action if it would cause the number of clicked elements to be zero.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click",function(evt) {               
     if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 0) {
         evt.preventDefault();
     }                                                        
});
```